# MySQL tree structure

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case, greatest-n-per-group

Hello i am trying to prepare tree structure with MySql, tables look something like this.

```
 |id   |parent_id |               |entry_id| name  |lang  |
 |-----|----------|               |--------|-------|------|
 |   1 |    0     |               |       1| ABC   | eng  |
 |   2 |    1     |               |       1| BCD   | fra  |
 |   3 |    2     |               |       2| EFG   | eng  |
 |   4 |    2     |               |       2| HIJ   | fra  |
 |   5 |    2     |               |       3| WYX   | eng  |
```

My Question is:

1. Is it possible to do left join and sort columns by name, but if in lang is eq to "fra" return  that row with that name, otherwise return "eng" name.

Pseudo code

```
SELECT id, name FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 ON id = entity_id 
WHERE (IF lang = 'fra' return french name otherwise return just english name) GROUP BY entry_id ORDER BY name ASC
```

So final result will be something like this, in total "fra" lang has priority, and all result should be sorted by name.

```
        |      id| name  |lang  |
        |--------|-------|------|
        |       1| BCD   | fra  |
        |       2| HIG   | fra  |
        |       3| WYX   | eng  |
```

Comment: What is preventing you from trying this?

Comment: i am not sure how to write "if statement", if both languages exist return just a "french" ignore "english", but if "english" is only available just return it.

Comment: like adding something in HAVING lang = "fra" but if not exist return just a "eng"

Comment: any idea maybe something with sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, give it a try:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   name,
   CASE WHEN tfra.entry_id is null THEN teng.name ELSE tfra.name END as name 
FROM table 
LEFT JOIN table2 tfra ON id = tfra.entity_id AND tfra.lang='fra'
LEFT JOIN table2 teng ON id = teng.entity_id AND teng.lang='eng'
WHERE (IF lang = 'fra' return french name otherwise return just english name) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: tnx sir looks like it's working thx million times!

Comment: please can you up vote question if you find it use full tnx!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend window functions:

```
select entity_id, name, lang
from (
    select t2.*,
        row_number() over(partition by entity_id order by field(lang, 'fra', 'eng')) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2
where rn = 1
```

If you needed to join the other table (which is not obvious from your sample data), you would do:

```
select t1.*, t2.name, t2.lang
from table1 t1
left join (
    select t2.*,
        row_number() over(partition by entity_id order by field(lang, 'fra', 'eng')) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.id and t2.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split table2 into 2 tables, one with just english entries and the other with just french, and joined those on id, you would then have a table with single row for each id with the information necessary to tell which language's name to use.

Comment: yes, thx, but i can modify table structure

Comment: Do the split-and-join using subqueries within your SQL.